# Viewport like Angry Bird in Corona

Tags: lua

Not sure if that's the right name for it, but I'm looking for a way to implement zooming in my game.

Essentially the game should zoom in on my character during the moving and shooting phase (its like Worms), but zoom out when the character has shot (preferably by following the shot, like Angry Birds does).

Can Corona/Lua do something like this?

Comment: I'm thinking you just need to scale the images on the screen to zoom in.

Comment: This [sort](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/2d-very-large-tile-based-game-zoom-and-pan-considerations) of [thing](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26507/how-do-i-properly-implement-zooming-in-my-game) has [been](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30357/3d-zooming-technique-to-maintain-the-relative-position-of-an-object-on-screen) asked [before](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27277/zooming-to-point-of-interest).

Comment: Doing this in Corona is a different problem than doing this in, say, OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can attach everything to the same group and then scale that group:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newGroup.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do it with scaling all images on the stage.
It's like scaling all display objects include physics and/or non-physics objects.

You can check out xScale, yScale features from [CoronaLabs](http://coronalabs.com) website.
Also, you should be careful about the reference points of the objects. Cause of, scaling depends on the reference point of the object that you scale.

If there are more specific questions in your mind about these usages, then please comment.